# How to determine placement of "more" link/button after multiline text break in react-native

Tags: react-native, text, caption

I want to implement caption breaking feature of instagram in a react-native app (a "more" link after long text break) but with the option of determining exact character position of line break to place "more" link.

For example if I have the following text in caption:

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, putant  ancillae voluptaria eos te, eum et justo impetus. Tincidunt efficiendi eu mei, sea at aeque persius. Quo commodo molestie similique eu, pri ei utroque lucilius. Eum cu everti iriure, in duo ludus urbanitas intellegam. Partiendo molestiae et eos, mei wisi cetero recteque ex.

and given `numberOfLines={2}`, it displays (say) one and a half line of text before "more" (not the exact 2 lines).

[Desired view of my example at this stage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ni4v.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is actually a library for this purpose:
[react-native-read-more-text](https://github.com/expo/react-native-read-more-text)

Here is the [discussion](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2496) in Github. Basically the idea is to use `computeLines` function to virtually calculate length of each line.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly it's gonna help you or not. But this is what I did in my case. And it worked for me

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';

export default class Myapp extends React.Component<{}> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      text: '...more' + '\n',
      number: 2,
    };
    this.dl =
      'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, putant ancillae voluptaria eos te, eum et justo impetus. Tincidunt efficiendi eu mei, sea at aeque persius. Quo commodo molestie similique eu, pri ei utroque lucilius. Eum cu everti iriure, in duo ludus urbanitas intellegam. Partiendo molestiae et eos, mei wisi cetero recteque ex.sddaefrwtttb tguirdg';
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text numberOfLines={this.state.number} ellipsizeMode={'middle'}>
          {this.dl.substr(0, 80)}
          <Text
            onPress={() =>
              this.setState({ number: null, text: this.dl.substr(80) })
            }>
            {this.state.text}
          </Text>
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    padding: 8,
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
```

It's not perfect but I think it will give you the idea
[Expo Link](https://snack.expo.io/@masukhelal/cmVhZC)